# Alternative to the idiomatic phrase "highway robbery"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-requests, slang

I was wondering whether there were any other alternatives to the phrase "highway robbery". I am trying to say the same thing in a light-hearted, but not too casual way.

Comment: I'm curious -- do you think "highway robbery" is too casual, or not light-hearted enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be light-hearted, you could use dramatic understatement and say *a bit pricey*.

You also could comment on whether you could afford to commit both *an arm AND a leg* to the purchase.

You might suggest that you are comfortable with *being taken for a ride*, but not with *being run over*.

You could indicate you like a neat appearance, but that doesn't mean you want to be *taken to the cleaners* or *cleaned out*.

You also might indicate your mild reluctance to *being ripped off*.

Answer (score 3):

The other day I discovered the phrase ***clean shave*** that applies.

OED definintion:

> a complete swindle or extortion.

It derives from a rather rare sense of *shave* meaning to strip someone clean of money or possessions. ([sense 4](http://thinkexist.com/dictionary/meaning/shave/))

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **exorbitant**, **extortionate** or **overcharging**.

Comment: While the OP's request is a bit vague, none of those words are particularly lighthearted.

Comment: It would depend on the tone/context. An over-the-top exclamation with mock indignation of 'That's extortionate!' could be lighthearted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to that durable hippie creation **ripoff** or feisty synonyms like **mugging**, but the context may be amenable to a playful neologism like, um, say... **swindlathon**?... **graspasm**?... **uberburglary**???...